# Docker for Windows Hyper V Default Switch IP

Tags: windows, docker

The Hyper V Default Switch IP changes between class C and D , so after each reboot you get 172.17.x.x or 192.168.x.x. 
That seems a well known "feature" of all windows 10 installations so far I could read.

My question is, why a running docker container - out of the box, without any additional docker network bridges - can't communicate to the internet if the Hyper Default switch stays on 172.17.x.x

It works only if I got the 192.168.x.x. I assume the reason is, that the Docker default switch is also 172.x.x.x.

How can I configure a stable network for my running container configuration regarding the current behavior of the Hyper V Default switch  on Windows 10?

route print - Output:

```
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
  8...54 bf 64 a6 c1 0a ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
  9...00 15 5d e5 81 12 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
 20...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
  2...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 21...96 15 9f 09 b1 88 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.8.32.1      10.8.40.242      6
        10.0.75.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung         10.0.75.1    271
        10.0.75.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         10.0.75.1    271
      10.0.75.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         10.0.75.1    271
        10.8.32.0    255.255.240.0   Auf Verbindung       10.8.40.242    259
      10.8.40.242  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       10.8.40.242    259
      10.8.47.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       10.8.40.242    259
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.60.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung      192.168.60.1    291
     192.168.60.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.60.1    291
   192.168.60.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.60.1    291
  192.168.137.144  255.255.255.240   Auf Verbindung   192.168.137.145   5256
  192.168.137.145  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung   192.168.137.145   5256
  192.168.137.159  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung   192.168.137.145   5256
    192.168.254.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.254.1    291
    192.168.254.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.254.1    291
  192.168.254.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.254.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung      192.168.60.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.254.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         10.0.75.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung       10.8.40.242    259
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung   192.168.137.145   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.60.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.254.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         10.0.75.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       10.8.40.242    259
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung   192.168.137.145   5256
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
  Keine

IPv6-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
 If Metrik Netzwerkziel             Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  Auf Verbindung
  1    331 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
  Keine
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to Default Switch . 
We can fix it by creating a seperate switch and configure it with NATTING

```
Open Hyper-V Manager (Windows search : “Hyper-V …”)
Go to Virtual Switch Manager on the right side.
Go to DockerNAT then choose Connection type -> to External network -> #which interface you deside.
```

Created a windows nanoserver container , configured NIC for Docker to NAT and it works fine on a windows 10 Machine

PS C:> docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 ping google.com

```
Pinging google.com [216.58.203.206] with 32 bytes of data: 
Reply from 216.58.203.206: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=55 
Reply from 216.58.203.206: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=55 
Reply from 216.58.203.206: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=55 
Ping statistics for 216.58.203.206: Packets: Sent = 4, 
Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Also, I am not certain why its hanging. Are you using unix Containers or Win ?

Comment: If I do this I can't start my container anymore, it hangs. And my PC has also no internet connection. Obv. if the physical network is shared from docker and the defaut switch of the host, that does not work.

Comment: Done, see above

Comment: Created a windows nanoserver container , configured NIC for Docker to NAT and it works fine on a windows 10 Machine
PS C:\> docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 ping google.com

Pinging google.com [216.58.203.206] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.203.206: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=55
Reply from 216.58.203.206: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=55
Reply from 216.58.203.206: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 216.58.203.206:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Also, I am not certain why its hanging. Are you using unix Containers or Win ?